# JQuery after input from db

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

This code:

```
jQuery('#FreeProlongation').on('change', function() {              
        if($(this).val() == "False"){}}
```

works very good. 
Although when I'm changing the value of FreeProlongation (without changing it myself) via a column which gets the data from the db, the event doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: please make question readable. http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: user `trigger()` to trigger a change event on the button click.  http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: trigger() isn't working. It doesnt really change the value from a 'button'  but via a column. Its hard to explain, its a very complicated application.

Comment: does your pack postback after value is changed view DB?

Answer (score 0):

If the value is updated via AJAX or WebSockets or something similar that handles the update to the value within Javascript, then definitely JQuery trigger is what you need to trigger an event that you can add a handler for (using .on) to recognise that the value has been updated and to update your field.  If, however, the change is being made elsewhere (for example a direct change to the value in the database, or from a separate application somewhere), then you're going to need some way to tell your client-side Javascript that this has happened, or else you're going to need to do something that polls the server at regular intervals to refresh the value you display in your field.  See (http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr) for one option if you're using .NET on the server side.

Comment: Fixed it by changing the way the applications works. I just call a javascript method every time, when there is a click on a column.The method checks if its checked or not. Thanks guys for the help.